# Display integer <li> in Django

Tags: html, django

is there anyone will share me how print out integer from models.py on front page (html) with li, example template

```html
<ul class="a big">
            <li class="a">1</li>
            <li class="a">2</li>
            <li class="a">3</li>
            <li class="a">4</li>
            <li class="a">5</li>
            <li class="extra"></li>
</ul>
```

on the models of Django I write class Number and the inside
numb = models.IntegerField()
then in views I wrote
makenumb = Number.objects.values_list('numb', flat=True).distinct()
in the html I using for loop
{% for i in makenumb %}
{% endfor %}
But at the html display, the number was showing whole number, and not splitted on by.

Actually when at the Django admin will input 123456, at the template will showing

```html
<ul class="a big">
            <li class="a">1</li>
            <li class="a">2</li>
            <li class="a">3</li>
            <li class="a">4</li>
            <li class="a">5</li>
            <li class="extra"></li>
</ul>
```

And the current problem is, when at the Django admin input 123456, the template was showing

```html
<ul class="a big">
            <li class="a">123456</li>
            <li class="a">123456</li>
            <li class="a">123456</li>
            <li class="a">123456</li>
            <li class="a">123456</li>
            <li class="extra">123456</li>
</ul>
```

Regards, Thank you

Comment: It is better to share your view and template code. `<ul>{% for i in makenumb %}<li>{{ i }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>`

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking

Comment: Hi @MeL I was edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Change your template code to

```
    <ul>
        {% for i in makenumb %}
            <li>
                {{ i }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

{%for i makenumb%} is false

Comment: I was typo, but i really write for i in makenumb